# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, crash

I am currently working on an assignment for my college classes to create an AVL tree with a menu that allows the user to input an item (integer) to add to the tree. The only method I've typed so far is the add routine which passes the users input to an Add routine which then passes it to a method in a class. However, without any syntax errors I can build the solution and it builds somewhat sluggishly. When I hit f5 or try to debug, Visual Studio simply appears to load. It does not crash but I have to force close it in task manager. The code I have is below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
int data;
Node * left;
Node * right;
int balance;
};

typedef Node * ptrNode;

class AVLTree
{
private:
Node * root = NULL;
Node ** trav = &root;

public:

void AddItem(int item);
void deleteNode(int item);
void clearTree();
void inorder();
void showtree();



void Add(int item)
{
    AddItem(root, item);
}
void AddItem(Node *&trav, int item)
{


if (trav == NULL)
    {
        trav = new Node;
        trav->data = item;
    }
    else if (trav->data > item)
    {
        AddItem(trav->left, item);
    }
    else
    {
        AddItem(trav->right, item);
    }
}
};





void main()
{
int choice;
int item;
AVLTree tree;
cout << (This is a menu here, I omitted it since I'm fairly positive it's not causing this)
cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    cout << "Enter number to add: ";
    cin >> item;
    tree.Add(item);

    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Are you saying your program is crashing and/or locking up, or that Visual Studio is crashing/locking up?

Comment: Is `{` missed after `case 1:`? Of course it ain't the error source. Try to remove some code and debug that version.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which is crashing, once I hit debug it simply just stops responding, it seems to be Visual Studio since I can no longer select anything on screen and I'm forced to end it. I will also debug the certain chunks to see if that resolves the issue, Thanks for input so far!

Comment: Edit #2: Literally sent a friend with same Visual Studio as me my exact code and his runs fine.

Comment: This could be hardware issues, or your antivirus deciding to do a full system scan while you're trying to load VS, or something else is running that is pounding on your hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem while I was trying to run it on my laptop. But the program runs fine on school's computer. Try disable your Anti-virus software temporarily

Comment: This worked! Is there anything else that can be done so it does not have to be disabled, for future reference?

Comment: @ChrisHoffer: You should be able to add an exception for your "\Visual Studio 2013\Projects" folder in the antivirus settings.